# How to tune query to fetch result faster | Oracle 19c |

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I have a table which as huge records in table

**My tables :** `employee` and `customer`

Now the issue here is I have 2 billion records in `employee` table and 1 billion records in `customer` table

**Employee columns**

```
empid
empname
empage
empdcourse
```

**Customer columns**

```
custid 
custdesc
custmessage
```

**My query :**

```
select emp_id from employee where empid not in (  select custid from customer);
```

**Error :** It throws me table space issue. Not allowed to increase table space

Is their any way I can tune my query or run in batch by batch so I get output

Any solution is much appreciated !!!

Need it on high priority

Comment: Is columns employee.empid = customer.custid? Do you have indexes for empid and custid columns? What columns are in the table customer?

Comment: @ilsurealism : No index it as ... if it can be achieved using indexing how to implement it

Comment: @ilsurealism : I have updated the question with column names

Comment: If you only want the IDs in one table that aren't in the other then you can use `MINUS`. But what will you do with the results - if those IDs are unique then your result set will still be at least a billion rows...

Comment: Please post the table structure and execution plan. But as @ilsurealism mentioned, it seems odd to expect employee.empid to match customer.custid.

Answer (score 1):

NOT EXISTS may be more efficient and less memory consuming in such case.

(The query suggests Customer and Employee share the same PK, does it mean you have an "super" table Person ?)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
with tmp as
 (select /*+full(c)*/
         custid
    from customer c)
select /*+full(e)*/
       e.emp_id
  from employee e, tmp t
 where e.empid = t.custid(+)
   and t.custid is null;
```

The hint full will prevent the tablespace issue.
The OUTER JOIN is faster than the NOT IN.
You can improve it by adding the hint parallel, starting with a degree=2 or 4 like this:

```
with tmp as
 (select /*+full(c) parallel(c,2)*/
         custid
    from customer c)
select /*+full(e) parallel(e,2)*/
       e.emp_id
  from employee e, tmp t
 where e.empid = t.custid(+)
   and t.custid is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add indexes for columns, for example, if they aren’t primary keys:

```
CREATE INDEX empid_index
ON employee(empid);
```

Also, you can update the query:

```
select e.empid from employee e where not exists (select 1 from customer c where c.custid = e.empid);
```

Comment: Any other way to do it